# How can I change the color of Focused prefixIcon icon color in TextFiled?

Tags: dart, flutter

[image: TextField Image]

I want to change the color of the `prefixIcon` to same as the `focusedInputBorder` color. I have tried with ThemeData in very root of the app but no luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The color of the `prefixIcon` is controlled via the `primaryColor` of your theme.

You can adjust it only for the `TextField` by wrapping it inside of a `Theme`:

```dart
Theme(data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(primaryColor: Color(..)), child: TextField(..))
```

Answer (score 2):

I am new to flutter. But when I tried as below it changes the `preFixIcon` color:  (do not mind the indentation. It is not well indented)

```
TextField(
 obscureText: false,
 style: TextStyle(
 color: Colors.white,
 fontSize: 15.0,
 fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
 ),
  decoration: new InputDecoration(
  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.vpn_key,
  color: Colors.white,),
  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all( Radius.circular(20)),
  borderSide: BorderSide( width: 1, color: Colors.white),),
  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
  borderSide: BorderSide( width: 1, color: Colors.white),),
  hintText: 'Password',
  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 15)
 ),
 )
```

Below is the expected output I got: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
List<FocusNode> _focusNodes = [
  FocusNode(),
  FocusNode(),
];

  @override
  void initState() {
    _focusNodes.forEach((node){
    node.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  });
    super.initState();
  }
```

---

```
TextFormField(
            focusNode: _focusNodes[0],
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.alternate_email,
                  color: _focusNodes[0].hasFocus ? Colors.green : Colors.grey,
                ),
                hintText: "Email"),
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Flutter 3.3.2

can do like this.

```
Icon(
  ...
  color: FocusScope.of(context).isFirstFocus ? colorA : colorB
  ...
)
```